# Why const is not shown in the output by typeid().name(), c++

Tags: c++, constants, typeid

I am a beginner in c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    const int i = 10;
    std::cout << typeid(i).name() << std::endl;
}
```

The type of `i` should be `const int`, but why the results is `int` on my laptop? I am using windows 10, Visual studio IDE.

Comment: The type is int. Const is just an annotation for readonly and a restriction for the programmer.

Comment: @chris01 No, `const int` is a different type than `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `i` is `const int` indeed, but the `std::type_info` object returned from `typeid(i)` does refer to `int`; because `const` is ignored by [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid#Explanation).

> In all cases, cv-qualifiers are ignored by typeid (that is, `typeid(T) == typeid(const T)`)

Comment: Meh, the type of `i` still is `const int`, the fact that typeid ignores const doesn't change that.